# Jenkins active choice reactive reference plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Choice parameter "Product" which has multiple options to choose from, i need to Provide the user to select the option to Run build(Yes/No) only if the product parameter selected is "hox". Attached is how i have defined. But when i click on Build parameters it throws exception, what is the problem here?[image]